# awk: find and replace in certain field only

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
$ cat test
12 13 2100 s
12 13 3100 s
100 13 100 s
12 13 300 s
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
$ cat test
12 13 22000 s
12 13 32000 s
100 13 2000 s
12 13 300 s
```

I only want to replace `100` in field 3 (once `100` is contained in `$3`) into `2000`. How can I accomplish this job using `awk`?

Comment: jww et all, awk is a programming language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK: "AWK is a programming language designed for text processing and typically used as a data extraction and reporting tool."

Comment: If you want to find and replace something even a bit more complex, I'd suggest using `perl -npe` instead. For example something like `cat test | perl -npe 's#^(\d+\s+\d+\s+\d*)(100)#$12000#'`. It's doable with `awk` but you have to use `sub()` or similar functions and it quickly turns into totally unmaintainable mess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub(/100$/, "2000", $3) }1' file
```

Results:

```
12 13 22000 s
12 13 32000 s
100 13 2000 s
12 13 300 s
```

Comment: How can I replace everything that is not 100 with lets say 5000 ?

Comment: @lovedynasty: You could try something like: `awk '{ sub(/[^1]*[^0]*[^0]*/, "5000", $3) }1' file`. But that may not provide you with the expected results. Usually when I want to perform some sort of inverse pattern matching, I would want to use some sort of [look-around assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Unfortunately, `awk` doesn't support these and I would need use a more powerful tool. I would use `perl` in 'auto-split' mode instead. HTH.

Comment: what's th point of `1` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$3~/100/{gsub(/100/,"2000",$3)}1' your_file
```

Comment: sorry, I have not describe problem properly, I have updated my problem.

Comment: How can I replace everything that is not 100 with lets say 5000 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '{$3=gensub(100,2000,1,$3);print}' test.txt
```