# Awk will not replace in all columns

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I'm trying to replace in a certain column of a file using awk [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054791/awk-find-and-replace-in-certain-field-only). I can get it to work to replace the "r" in column 3 using

```
awk '{ sub(/r$/, "Q", $3) }1' temp2.txt
```

Or the "4" in column 6 using

```
awk '{ sub(/4$/, "Q", $6) }1' temp2.txt
```

However, I cannot do the replace on the "T" in column 4.

The contents of the file are

```
cat temp2.txt

224245  CO2_Cells_50_V_-100_P_760   r  2016-08-18T13:35:12.337  long@d6copt025.crc.nd.edu   4
224256  CO2_Cells_100_V_-200_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:15.408  long@d6copt039.crc.nd.edu   4
224261  CO2_Cells_100_V_-250_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:16.425  long@d6copt012.crc.nd.edu   4
224262  CO2_Cells_150_V_-250_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:16.426  long@d6copt075.crc.nd.edu   4
224264  CO2_Cells_250_V_-250_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:17.438  long@d6copt142.crc.nd.edu   4
224266  CO2_Cells_100_V_-300_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:17.440  long@d6copt145.crc.nd.edu   4
224267  CO2_Cells_150_V_-300_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:17.442  long@d6copt149.crc.nd.edu   4
224268  CO2_Cells_200_V_-300_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:17.443  long@d6copt143.crc.nd.edu   4
224269  CO2_Cells_250_V_-300_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:18.460  long@d6copt128.crc.nd.edu   4
224271  CO2_Cells_100_V_-350_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:18.463  long@d6copt136.crc.nd.edu   4
224272  CO2_Cells_150_V_-350_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:18.464  long@d6copt207.crc.nd.edu   4
224273  CO2_Cells_200_V_-350_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:18.466  long@d6copt201.crc.nd.edu   4
224274  CO2_Cells_250_V_-350_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:19.539  long@d6copt226.crc.nd.edu   4
224277  CO2_Cells_150_V_-400_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:19.543  long@d6copt250.crc.nd.edu   4
224278  CO2_Cells_200_V_-400_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:19.545  long@d6copt212.crc.nd.edu   4
224279  CO2_Cells_250_V_-400_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:20.649  long@d6copt184.crc.nd.edu   4
224282  CO2_Cells_150_V_-450_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:20.653  long@d6copt074.crc.nd.edu   4
224283  CO2_Cells_200_V_-450_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:20.654  long@q16copt062.crc.nd.edu  4
224287  CO2_Cells_150_V_-500_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:21.718  long@d6copt030.crc.nd.edu   4
224288  CO2_Cells_200_V_-500_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:21.720  long@q16copt063.crc.nd.edu  4
224289  CO2_Cells_250_V_-500_P_760  r  2016-08-18T13:35:21.721  long@q16copt063.crc.nd.edu  4
224522  CO2_Cells_250_V_-450_P_760  r  2016-08-18T14:54:09.720  long@d6copt030.crc.nd.edu   4
224699  CO2_Cells_50_V_-150_P_760   r  2016-08-18T18:04:18.900  long@q16copt062.crc.nd.edu  4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` in your regular expressions matches end of string - i.e. it will only replace text on the end of column.
If you want to replace a text anywhere in the column use `sub(/T/, "Q", $4)`, but it will only replace first matched text.

To replace all 'T's in a column, use `gsub` instead of `sub`

Answer (score 1):

Try: `awk '{ sub(/[[T]/, "XYZ", $4) }1'`

The sub first param `/[[T]/` can contain any char need to replace – for your case then `T`.

Comment: There is no benefit of `/[[T]/` over just `/T/`.

Comment: Agree, it was more for an example in case more than one char needs to be replaced.